# Number of roots of a multivariate polynomial

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

What could be the best known asymptotic for the number of solution of the following polynomial in $(F_p)^s$:
$$
(1-x_1)(1-x_2)\cdots(1-x_s)(1-x_1x_2...x_s)=ux_1x_2...x_s
$$
where $u$ is a non-zero element of $F_p$.

Comment: 1. Please use TeX on this site. 2. Please ask the question in the main body of your post, not in the title. 3. Please use a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory". I added this tag now. 4. "asymptomatic" is a medical term (cf. Google).

Comment: Do you need asymptotic for fixed $p$ and large $s$ or fixed $s$ and large $p$ or anything else?

Comment: Intuitively there are about $p^{s-1}$ solutions when $p$ is odd. Choose $x_1,\dots,x_{s-1}$ arbitrarily. One obtains a quadratic equation for $x_s$, which should have no solutions about half the time and two solutions about half the time.

Comment: I need an asymptotic relation for fixed s with large p.

Comment: @RatiSasmol: for fixed $s$ and large $p$ I would conjecture that the number of solutions is asymptotically $p^{s-1}$.

Comment: Thanks. Could you also see what is the size of the error term ? I mean is it $p^{s-1}+O(p^{s-2})$